# Android ListView repeating items on scrolling

Tags: java, android, listview, baseadapter

I'm working on Android project. one of my activities has inner class ChatHistoryAdapter.
when activity starts, the list is shown correctly, but after scrolling, some items are duplicated. I've searched for solutions, but almost every solution was to setTag() or Inflater. I think my code is ok with them..
so I cann't really understand whats the problem here...

```
private class ChatHistoryAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public ChatHistoryAdapter( LayoutInflater inflater) {
        this.inflater = inflater;
    }

    public void newOne() {
        notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return messages.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return messages.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View myView, ViewGroup vg) {
        MessageHolder messageHolder;

        if (myView == null){
            myView = this.inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_list_item, null, false);
            messageHolder = new MessageHolder();
            messageHolder.hisTxt = (TextView)myView.findViewById(R.id.hisText);
            messageHolder.myTxt = (TextView)myView.findViewById(R.id.myText);
            myView.setTag(messageHolder);
        } else {
            messageHolder = (MessageHolder) myView.getTag();
        }

        Message mes = messages.get(position);

        if (mes.myMessage()){
                messageHolder.myTxt.setText(mes.toString());
        } else{
                messageHolder.hisTxt.setText(mes.toString());
        }

        return myView;
    }

}

private static class MessageHolder{
    TextView hisTxt;
    TextView myTxt;
}
```

here is part where ArrayList is filled:

```
private void loadMessages() {
    this.messages = new ArrayList<Message>();
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            messages = dbMes.gettMessages(guest.getId()); // gettMessages is Synchronized
            chatHistoryAdapter = new ChatHistoryAdapter(getLayoutInflater());
            listView.setAdapter(chatHistoryAdapter);
        }
    };
    Thread T = new Thread(r);
    T.start();
}
```

[image]

Comment: the list contains the duplicates? or is the listview to create them? check the elements of the list.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are using ViewHolder pattern, you need "clean" the previous values.

Like this.

```
if (mes.myMessage()){

      messageHolder.myTxt.setText(mes.toString());
      messageHolder.hisTxt.setText("");

} else {

      messageHolder.myTxt.setText("");
      messageHolder.hisTxt.setText(mes.toString());
}
```

Hope its helps.

Comment: thank you man. working on it for several hours, tried everything but this.. +

Comment: I'am happy for helping :)
Please mark as correct answer.